# Automate an application in windows

Tags: python, windows, task, scheduler

I have been running an app every day using Task Scheduler. But I need to automate the click of a button inside that application. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use module name pyautogui.You can click button if it is visible on screen.Basically you give image of button which you want to click and it finds it on screen and clicks it.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('im.PNG'))
```

this is use to click on center of the image given to it